# Why is this call-by-value?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

this is my problem:

```
/**
* Example of the book:
* C++ Templates page 17/18
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

// max of two values of any type (call by reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

// max of two C-strings (call by value) 
inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b) {
    // ??? Creates this a new temporary local value that may be returned?
    // I can't see where the temporary value is created!
    return std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a;
}

// max of three values of any type (call by reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c) {
    return max (max(a,b),c); // warning "error", if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
                             // warning:  reference of temp value will be returned

int main() {
    // call by reference 
    std::cout << ::max(7, 42, 68) << std::endl;

    const char* s1 = "Tim";
    const char* s2 = "Tom";
    const char* s3 = "Toni";
    // call the function with call by value
    // ??? Is this right?
    std::cout << ::max(s1,s2) << std::endl;

    std::cout << ::max(s1, s2, s3) << std::endl;
}
```

Where is the temporary local value in the function max for C-strings?

The function gets two pointers, so why is it a call by value?

Sorry, i think it is a very stupid question, but i don't understand it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the temporary local value in the function max for C-strings?

The following:

```
return std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const char *ret = std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a;
return ret;
```

I expect the "temporary local value" in question is the unnamed equivalent of `ret`.

> The function gets two pointers, so why is it a call by value?

Each C string is represented by `const char*`, and the `const char*` is passed by value. The implication is that if the function were to modify `a` or `b` (i.e. the pointers themselves), the modification would not be visible to the caller.